# Hive function to retrieve particular array element

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table which stores strings in array. Couldn't figure it out why but simple example looks like that:

```
+--------+----------------------------------+
| reason |              string              |
+--------+----------------------------------+
| \N     | \N\N\N\NXXX - ABCDEFGH\N\N |
| \N     | \N\N\N\NXXX - ABCDEFGH       |
| \N     | \N\N\N\N                      |
| \N     | \N\N\N\NXXX - ABCDEFGH\N    |
| \N     | \N\N                            |
| \N     | \N\N\N                         |
| \N     | \N                               |
+--------+----------------------------------+
```

We couldn't see that in table above but true format of first string looks like that 
[image]

Basically, what I would like to retrieve is:

```
+--------+----------------------------------+
| reason |              string              |
+--------+----------------------------------+
| \N     |          XXX - ABCDEFGH          |
+--------+----------------------------------+
```

XXX - remains always the same but ABCDEFGH may be any string. 
The problem is I can't use table path.path.path_path[4] because string XXX - ABCDEFGH may be 4th or any element of the array (even 20th).

Tried to use `where lower(path.path.string) like ('xxx - %')` but received error

```
Select 
path.path.reason, 
path.path.string
From table_name
Where path.id = '123'
And datestr = '2018-07-21'
```

Comment: you should add your table definition and the queries of the results that we are seeing. i does not seem to be an array... question is not clear at all either

Comment: What is the code of strings delimiter?

Comment: Hint: `SELECT regexp_extract('\N\N\N\NXXX - ABCDEFGH\N\N', '\N\N\N\N(.*?)(\N\N)', 1)`

Comment: What is that character as show in image?

Answer (score 1):

This **regular expression** will do the job for you`([^\N$])+`.

Assuming the character showed in the image is a `$`.

**First**,
 you can use `regexp_extract()` to retrieve particular array element.
It has the following syntax:

```
regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)
```

**Second**, you can use `regexp_replace` which has the following syntax:

```
regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT)
```

Test Data

```
WITH string_column 
     AS (SELECT explode(array('XXX - ABCSSSSSSSSSSSGH\N\N', 
                    '\N$\N$\N$\N$XXX - ABCDEFGH$\N\N', 
                    '\N\N\N\N', '\N\N\N\NXXX - ABCDEFGH\N')) AS 
            str_column
        ) 
SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_extract(str_column, '([^\N$])+', 0), "$", " ") 
    AS string_col 
FROM string_column
```

Will result in

```
------------------------------
|         string_col         |
------------------------------
| XXX - ABCSSSSSSSSSSSGH     |
------------------------------
| XXX - ABCDEFGH             |
------------------------------
|                            |
------------------------------
| XXX - ABCDEFGH             |
------------------------------
```

## Note: A '0' which specifies the index produces a match, after the extract based on the pattern.

```
regexp_extract(str_column, '(,|[^\N$])+', 0)
```

## The following statement will replace occurrence of any '$'

```
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(str_column, '([^\N$])+', 0), "$", " ")
```

For more information on

- **regexp_replace** & **regexp_extract()**: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

Comment: Wow, thanks for comprehensive answer. I have to admit it looks realy tricky as after I retreive those strings (every string starts with "XXX - " and then there is a string which may be 5 characters or 100 characters long) I want to use joins etc so it may get much more complicated for me but thank you once again! You asked in comment above what's that character in the picture - I have no idea... if there is a way to check that, please let me know ;)

Comment: Can you show me the hive definition for this table?